# Update the exist database on server entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two databases first is local sql server, second is work server.
On developers server i am testing,  removing changing structure of tables. Now i need to update work server with all changes. But i can't drop any information from database. How can i do it correctly without losing information from tables?

Comment: How do you update the Database for dev server?

Comment: There are a variety of approaches, depending on the tools you use and what your team prefers.  Some teams create manual change and rollback scripts.  Some point a SQL comparison tool at the two databases to generate change and rollback scripts.  Personally I prefer maintaining a SQL Server project in my .NET solution and only making changes to that project, never directly to the database.  The deployment process would then effectively generate the change script to be executed either automatically or by the DBA.  (In many environments the latter is preferred for production changes.)

Comment: Via Update-Database command, but i can't connect my studio to work server.

Comment: please refer following link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1080272/Free-SQL-Server-Schema-Comparison-Tool-in-Visual-S  it will guide Step by step guide you

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I'm trying so.